# Question about Train DDPG Agent for Adaptive Cruise Control in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, reinforcement-learning, ddpg

I have one question about the [Train DDPG Agent for Adaptive Cruise Control](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2021a/deeplearning/ug/train-ddpg-agent-for-adaptive-cruise-control.html) example in MATLAB. The speed of the lead car is sine wave using fixed-value parameters: amplitude, bias, frequency, and phase. So the agent can explore and learn the environment using the exactly same lead car speed profile (red line in the following figure) every time.

[image: Lead car speed in red]
[image: Parameters of the lead car speed]

However, if the speed profile of lead car varies, for instance I have N speed profiles known in advance, the goal is to train an agent (ego car) that can adapt to all speed profiles of lead car. Is it still achievable using DDPG?